# Rules data selection tokens

Tags: rules, tokens

I have *[order:products:0:node:author:uid]* as rules data selection token. In data selection mode that works perfectly, and adds the exact data right where I need it, but when I add that token into the database table, using *Execute custom PHP code* and the following this code, I get only a blank *destination* field with no value.

```php
$nid = db_insert('mytable') ->fields(array(
  'uid' => $uid,
  'username' => $username,
  'addr' => $address,
  'destination' => "[order:products:0:node:author:uid]"
))
  ->execute();
```

All the other fields are filling correctly.

What could the problem be?

Comment: Actually now I am receiving "[order:products:0:node:author:uid]" in the value of the needed field, but I am receiving that as a text, not as actual uid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that kind of tokens are not being replaced, because god only knows why, but I solved my problem by adding variable to the needed rule, placing it before the executing php code, and selecting user entity by data selection there, and making reference to it in a php code. That is how it worked. Thank you, Jdrupal for your answer, anyway, it is always helpful to learn something new.